# order of items returned by Dictonary<>.Keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

if I do a `foreach` loop on `Dictionary<>.Keys`, 
is there any rules such as first-in-first-out, or last-in-first-out? or is it random?

Comment: You might want a List<> ,  you will have a lot more control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Items in the dictionary are not ordered. You can't be sure about getting the same items in the same order.

For its property [Dictionary.Keys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx)

> The order of the keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection is
>   unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the
>   Dictionary.ValueCollection returned by the Values
>   property.

If you want Order or want to access the dictionary item by index, then you may use [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)

> Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are accessible by the
>   key or index.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx).

> **The order of the keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection is
>   unspecified**, but it is the same order as the associated values in the
>   Dictionary.ValueCollection returned by the Values
>   property.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `dictionary is not deterministic`, you could not ensure the order while retrieving keys.

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined,
>   **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)**

*You can make a key in such a way that it tells you order e.g. you can use increamented integers as you add keys in dictionay or you can use [**ordered dictionary**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx).*